# Spring Data JPA passing dynamic column names as parameter to query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, microservices

I have table emp with columns emp_name, emp_desc, emp_age, emp_country, emp_pincode.

I am using Spring data Jpa for database operations.

```
 @Repository
 public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Emp, String> {}
```

and empRepository.findAll(); fires a select * from emp table.

But I have a requirement like as follows

The client app would pass column names to select in the method as parameter and I want to fetch only those in Jpa not Findall().

How to acheive this in Jpa?

Comment: You don't need an `@Repository` annotation on repositories extended from Spring Datas `Repository` interface.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**
  To get the employee details based on emp_name
      `empRepository.findByEmpName(String empName);`